# Powershell Start-Process - notify when finished

Tags: powershell

So I am running a script to download from web and install a binary. I do that in a separate command prompt. When its done, prompt is closed. How can I know when that happened?

Example (from Windows 10) - `powershell Start-Process cmd "/C tasklist"`

Can I assign it to a variable and listen to some fallback function call, etc.? Like this pseudo code:

```
$process = powershell Start-Process cmd "/C tasklist"

while (!$process.done) {
  // do stuff
}
```

p.s. I am very new to PowerShell. So sorry if that doesnt make sence

Answer (score 0):

You could use WaitForExit()

```
$process = Start-Process cmd "/C tasklist" -PassThru 
$process.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: I already used another option `-Wait`, but this sugestion is interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PowerShell, you can use background jobs for scenario:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {cmd.exe /c tasklist}
while ($job.State -eq 'Running') {
    # do other stuff while waiting for job to complete
}
# To get the job results
Receive-Job $job
```

---

Based on your comments, adding `-Wait` makes `Start-Process` a synchronous command. At that point, you don't need `Start-Process`. You may as well just execute `cmd.exe /c tasklist`.